# Assign a nested objet's value based on delimited string in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got an interface like this

```
export interface User{
   name:string;
   address:Address;
   job:Job;
}

export interface Address{
   street:string;
   postcode:string;
}

export interface Job{
   industry:Industry;
   location:string;
   salary:number;
}

export interface Industry{
  name:string;
  sector:string;
}
```

So what I am trying to implement is to build a function which dynamically assigns the properties based on the delimitted string name of that object

like this

```
SetFunction(name:string){
  // if name is user.address.street
  // it should update corresponding item dyanamically.
}
```

Havent got any hint how to implement that.

Comment: Why do you call that "dynamically"? It's a buzzword. And you can't do this. What if `user.address` is null? What class should be instantiated?  There are of course workarounds by splitting and going `foo["bar"] = baz` but why would you want this?

Answer (score -1):

```
    SetFunction(name: string, value: any, obj: any = {}) {
      const properties = name.split(".");
      let current = obj;
      for (let i = 0; i < properties.length - 1; i++) {
        current = current[properties[i]] = current[properties[i]] || {};
      }
      current[properties[properties.length - 1]] = value;
    }
```

name: the string representing the property you want to set.

value: the value you want to set to the property.

obj: the object that you want to set the property on.